# Power Automate - Infinite Loop issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

This sounds so simple in my head, but Power Automate doesn't like it.
I have a library with a lookup column. I have a Flow created which takes the filename of the document and puts this name into a "Title" column. Then I can use a lookup column on the Title column to find all the files in the library.

I've used "**When a file is created or modified**". Yet this flow runs constantly. No files are being update or modified at 1am, yet it still runs over and over. I've had an automated email telling me to fix this before it is disabled.

All I want it to do is run the damn flow **ONLY** when a file is updated or uploaded, just as its own function title suggested.

It would seem I need to add trigger rules, but all the guides I found were talking about checking if a specific person has modified it.

This used to be so simple with workflows, it would only run if something was modified or uploaded.